# In TFS 2015 how do find (using query) Test Cases which belongs to specific Test Suite

Tags: testing, tfs, tfs-2015

We use web based Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 to manage test cases/suites/plans.
If there is an way using TFS web based query to find Test Cases which belongs to specific Test Suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there is no way to create ordinary TFS query via Web interface and not API call or custom coding to get list of Test Cases belongs to a specific Test Suite.

Since from *TFS 2013 Update 3*, test plans and test suites are regular work items, but there are of no practical use in work item queries, as **there are no links between them and test cases.**

With the links, you could create a query to list all test cases in a specified test plan. There has been a feature request in ***uservoice***, you can also vote up for it to get more attention.

> **Support querying for "all test cases in a specifed test plan" a.k.a add work item links between test plans, test suites and test cases**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/12457410-support-querying-for-all-test-cases-in-a-specifed